# How to write a template that could be specialised with an object or an int N

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

What I'm trying to achieve is a template with a "flexible" first argument (which is most likely something like an array element, not unlike the first argument of `std::vector`) and a second argument. For that second argument, I want specialisations for the case where it's number (like the size parameter in a `std::array`), or a general class.

For a class `Foo`, I currently have

```
template <typename T, template <typename> typename Y > class Foo{};
```

The reason for that is that is then I think I can write the specialisation:

```
template<typename T> class Foo<T, int N>{};
```

and, given a `struct Bar{}`,

```
template<typename T> class Foo<T, Bar>{};
```

But the compiler (C++11, ideone.com), outputs the error "`error: template argument 2 is invalid`" on the lines with the specification.

Presumably I've formed the unspecialised declaration incorrectly. Or is this even possible?

Comment: you should post the code that's causing the problem, it's not very clear from your question what you are after..

Comment: Also what you have has typos so it should never compile.

Comment: Indeed the specialisations don't compile. That's my problem!

Comment: There are typo in `template<typename T> class Foo, int N>{};` (unbalanced `<`/`>`), not sure what you want.

Comment: I've added a sentence at the end that I hope makes this clearer for everyone. Do please let me know if it's still insufficient.

Comment: How about if you fix the syntax error pointed out.

Comment: Thank you. I've correct that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a helper template to wrap your integer and turn it into a type. This is the approach used, for instance, by Boost.MPL.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct int_ { }; // Wrapper

template <class> // General template for types
struct Foo { static constexpr char const *str = "Foo<T>"; };

template <int N> // Specialization for wrapped ints
struct Foo<int_<N>> { static constexpr char const *str = "Foo<N>"; };

template <int N> // Type alias to make the int version easier to use
using FooI = Foo<int_<N>>;

struct Bar { };

int main() {
    std::cout << Foo<Bar>::str << '\n' << FooI<42>::str << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Foo<T>
Foo<N>
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/488a589a9518041b)

Comment: or `template <int N> using int_ = std::integral_constant<int, N>;`